# Page number in the table of content doesn't appear correctly

Tags: pdftex

I have the following section in my latex:

```
 \section{Development environment and tools\\}
```

The problem is that the page number 4 doesn't appear in the same line but appear below the section title in the following line instead.

Does anyone know how to correct it ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `latex3` I'm afraid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove the `\\` at the end of the section title. `\\` (generally) means new line.

Like:

```
\section{Development environment and tools}
```

Answer (score 0):

SorenD answered the specific question here already. I just want to add a special case where the newline cannot be removed for some reason, for example as in:

```
 \section{Development:\\Environment and Tools}
```

If the line break is necessary for the section heading to look good, you can add an entry to the table of contents without the newlines in an optional parameter:

```
 \section[Development: Environment and Tools]{Development:\\Environment and Tools}
```